# colorbox popup image became mess code

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using colorbox function to display a photo album. The image is generated by system so that it cannot show its original file name but the path address like this: http://example.com/webcenter/wccproxy/d?dID=2602&Rendition=web.

When I click the thumbnail image, it showed the popup box with a pile of mess code. Like below:

> ================ JFIFC   %# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(C
>   (((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((0"
>   }!1AQa"q2#BR$3br
>   %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz
>   w!1AQaq"2B#3R$4&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz?hc##m
>   ܤ-m]y=k$3ld,uieAv`W+*蒜5C4@4/mc["[9)W"-%O>iUT8MiJtųyʷe&9Wd4A֯$QxmR)s}*ܰ8v HՈW13եc$>c 1&
>   'NmħҼip`ۯ&i+SiXMofc[ =
>   ۴zUwT3,dcC`ҼdǑRm%_$`VH&@ӃMP0)veeeaW'O
>   S 'l)˼IM5=yaؓYWsYw
>   vMGk!=*1WNrUB<۟vuMߥ*
>   "ՉĒOaϴ68BtC~nP:"m8ZUS0ݓ! 1w
>   p9j6B=*U)&h"HE* n{ǩ]8MD7HA%
>   n͕F~RqJ*ٕ*Hb9N
>   9G{e#"D[r^kWzV\~6I8,؊q\ֽYyݥ婕tgR¼WSzjљ$
>   4&1U$#nc5쬫1WޟJ)RwJGOH\0/p!e:utePnsҕ2|OSˑOF@Hc2T0]W\D[-lszׅ!sH1I偞;~5C/+eܳmy7c'fÖ5-N?iYU!fnzT.r,>Px\յS4c5wÆ2޺6p'
>
> =====

Can't colorbox plugin support path like this? As I previously used original file name without any problem. Please advise.

Comment: Maybe an encoding or mime-type problem? I don't think is jquery related... Seems to me a server side problem. By the way you could post some come, just to be sure ;)

Comment: It looks like your popup is displaying the url content as plain text instead of a jpeg image. Can you show the server-side code used in `d` to display the image ?

Comment: Thanks Luca & PinkTurtle,

Comment: var imgarray= new Array(
"2601",
"2604",
)
<div id="imagebox"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var tmpstring = "";
var portalpath = "http://ipaddress/webcenter/wccproxy/d?dID=";
for (i=0; i < imgarray.length; i++){
 tmpstring = tmpstring + "<div class='nailthumb-container'><a class='bigimage' href='"+portalpath+imgarray[i]+"&Rendition=web'><img src='"+portalpath+imgarray[i]+"'/></a></div>"
} 
$("#imagebox").html(tmpstring);
 
jQuery('.nailthumb-container').nailthumb({width:100,height:100});
$(".bigimage").colorbox({rel:'bigimage'});
});
</script>

Comment: Oh, I cannot post full coding here. Actually this javascript reads the value of array imgarray and use the colorbox plugin to build the album.